# Bouncy Castle method only works in debug mode

Tags: java, bouncycastle

If I run the code normally it throws an exception. Once I switch to debug mode it runs fine. Does anyone know why the following would ONLY run in debug mode? I have tried to deploy on a test server and it throws an exception too.

**Code breaks when trying to run extractPrivateKey.**

```
private PGPPrivateKey privateKeyFromSecretKey(PGPSecretKey secretKey, String pass) throws PGPException {
    return secretKey.extractPrivateKey(
    new JcePBESecretKeyDecryptorBuilder(
            new JcaPGPDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build()).setProvider("BC").build(pass.toCharArray()));
  }
```

I get the following exception.

```
org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException: exception on setup: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for MessageDigest(provider: BC)cannot be found.
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcaPGPDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder$1.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.PGPUtil.makeKeyFromPassPhrase(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.PBESecretKeyDecryptor.makeKeyFromPassPhrase(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKey.extractKeyData(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKey.extractPrivateKey(Unknown Source)
```

Other code that runs fine before getting to the privateKeyFromSecretKey function shown above.

```
private void encryptorInit(String publicKeyRing, boolean integrityCheck) throws IOException, PGPException {
    PGPPublicKey publicKey = readPublicKey(publicKeyRing);   

    JcePGPDataEncryptorBuilder PgpDataEncryptorBuilder = new JcePGPDataEncryptorBuilder(PGPEncryptedData.AES_256)
    .setWithIntegrityPacket(integrityCheck)
    .setSecureRandom(new SecureRandom())
    .setProvider("BC");

    encryptor = new PGPEncryptedDataGenerator(PgpDataEncryptorBuilder);
    encryptor.addMethod(new JcePublicKeyKeyEncryptionMethodGenerator(publicKey).setProvider("BC"));
}
```

Comment: I had a similar problem once. The solution was that I had an expression in the debugger, which got executed and caused side effects, causing the real application to behave really different with and without the debugger

Comment: Possibly the provider is not registered before running the code. Where do you perform `Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());`? (sheesh, I can type that line without looking at the screen). Just add the provider before the call (re-registering the provider doesn't hurt, it will only be added once).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes at the beginning of the class I perform"    static {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    }"